# How to delete a feed in Feedly?

Tags: feedly

I am not clear on how to remove a feed, for instance `A` in below example:

[image: feedly]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the feed and click `Delete`.

Tested in Chrome 77 and Edge on Windows 10.